# Does increased the size of width to 10000px in <td> so as to load correctly in IE8 has any bad effects

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I have an application which was built on IE6 which runs comfortably on IE7 as well as FF.But coming to IE8 all the CSS is completely broken and ruined the application.
 In the course of fixing the broken CSS it came to know most of the places its only width that was previously working is not getting proper width of which it being provided explicitly for all the required . 
Now on trail error method we had started off the value with 400px to more and finaly ended at 8000px where all the issues are resolved and the backward compatibilty is also fine with IE6 and IE7

```
  <td><div class="cornerOuterLL"></div></td> 
  <td class="containerOuter containerOuterPadding fullWidth" style="width: 4700px;"></td>
  <td><div class="cornerOuterLR"></div></td> 
</tr>
```

I know I am not solving the actual problem but found a solution,which not sure whether it effects the performance or not? whether the approach is correct

Thanks

Comment: Having to put widths in excess of 4000px to make a site work on all versions of IE and FF. Come on. You must be doing something horrible wrong. Have you tried an html-validator on your html pages and css files ?

Comment: I just validated my HTML document and found not much serious errors. actually the problem is using apache velocity framework which embeds all the <HTML> tags internally. But seriously I wanted to know what are the repurcusions of such enormous width

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag in the head section, and see if it works..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```